# How to calculate expected core file size

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb, coredump

How can I calculate the expected size of a coredump?

I have a truncated core file(coredump) from arm64 target. And I can find expected size of a core file(coredump), from output of `gdb-multiarch`.

```
BFD: warning: /home/.../core-m is truncated: expected core file size >= 748728320, found: 518127616
```

From above, I can find expected size of a coredump is 748728320 and its actual size is 518127616.

Now, I wonder how `gdb-multiarch` calculates the expected size of a coredump.

I can find size of each section, using `readelf -e` and I thought the sum of each section's size will be same with expected size of a core file. So I get the sum, but it is not equal to expected size of the coredump.

```
the sum: 748680864
expected size by `gdb-multiarch`: 748728320
```

How can I calculate this, correctly?

**UPDATE**

I've just got to know I can find the expected size of a coredump, from output of `readelf -e`. `readelf -e` shows offset and size of each segment. I got the result from my truncated coredump.

```
Program Headers:
Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
               FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
NOTE           0x000000000000b2f8 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
               0x000000000002b6a0 0x0000000000000000         0x0
LOAD           0x0000000000037000 0x000000556af44000 0x0000000000000000
               0x0000000000001000 0x00000000008cc000  R E    0x1000
...
LOAD           0x000000002c831000 0x0000007fca9c5000 0x0000000000000000
               0x00000000001da000 0x00000000001da000  RW     0x1000
```

From above, I can find offset and size of last segment. Offset is 0x2c831000, and size if 0x1da000. And expected size of dump will be 0x2c831000 + 0x1da000 = 0x2CA0B000(748728320). This is same with one from `gdb-multiarch`.

This approach can be used only if `readelf` is available. And I can't explain how the expected size of dump is calculated, still. I hope someone give me the explanation.

Comment: Seems you are quite close. Perhaps the difference is because gdb-multiarch uses some extrapolation heuristic? If you are really curious, maybe browse the code of gdb-multiarch, e.g. from https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/devel/gdb-multiarch

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but wouldn't a core dump exclude the read-only ELF sections and include allocated program memory not from the ELF file like stack, heap, and mmaps?

Comment: Perhaps the discrepancy is due to alignment of sections? (i.e. There's potentially padding between sections in the file, so the sum of their sizes is the total file size less total padding.)

Answer (score 2):

I use the following script, seems to work quite well.  As the comment explains, we simply find the largest LOAD section end offset in the file.  (Note that it accounts for sparse files.)

If I remember correctly, I lifted the technique from GDB's corefile loading code (or some similar standard tool that warns about corefile truncation).

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'exit 1' ERR  # Abort script on error.

if [[ $# != 1 ]] ; then
    echo "$( basename $0 ) <coreFile>"
    exit 1
fi

coreFile=$1

# Examine all LOAD sections in the corefile, calculate the file offset of each section's end,
# and find the largest offset.
expectedSize=$( readelf -l ${coreFile} | grep -A 1 LOAD |
    while read type offset etc && read fsize etc ; do
        echo $(( $offset + $fsize ))
    done | sort -n | tail -n 1 )

actualSize=$( du --block-size=1 --apparent-size ${coreFile} | cut -f1 )

physicalSize=$( du --block-size=1 ${coreFile} | cut -f1 )

if [[ ${actualSize} < ${expectedSize} ]] ; then
    echo "Physical size ${physicalSize}"
    echo "Expected logical size ${expectedSize}"
    echo "Actual logical size ${actualSize}"
    exit 2
fi
```

Comment: This approach still uses `readelf`, but seems to be a good way to calculate expected size of coredump.

Comment: If you don't have access to `readelf`, you can use `objdump -h` instead (you'll need to parse the output accordingly, of course).  If you don't have `objdump` or an equivalent either (yikes!), you can parse the ELF structures yourself.  If you want to write a helper app then language-specific ELF-parsing libraries are available (e.g. ELFIO for C++) - or you can simply google the ELF file format and start from scratch.